# New line when using serial communication with embedded c

Tags: c, embedded, microcontroller, pic

I'm learning embedded c for microcontrollers using a PICKIT. When I send the voltage readings from an LDR via serial communication to RealTerm I end up with the voltages just continuing on the line (see pic) and not starting a new line every reading, how would I change it to look like this? Thanks in advance.

```
0.9V
0.89V
0.9V
```

[RealTerm data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mllbd.png)

```
#pragma config FEXTOSC = HS     // External Oscillator mode Selection bits (HS (crystal oscillator)above 8 MHz; PFM set to high power)

#pragma config RSTOSC = EXTOSC_4PLL// Power-up default value for COSC bits (EXTOSC with 4x PLL, with EXTOSC operating per FEXTOSC bits)


// CONFIG3L

#pragma config WDTE = OFF        // WDT operating mode (WDT enabled regardless of sleep)
#include <xc.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "LCD.h"`
#include "serial.h"
#include ADC.h

define _XTAL_FREQ 64000000 //note intrinsic _delay function is 62.5ns at 64,000,000Hz  

void main(void) {
LCD_Init(); 
initUSART4();   //Initialise EUSART4
ADC_init();

char LDR_arr[16];
unsigned int x;
unsigned int int_part; //initialise int part of voltage
unsigned int frac_part; // initialise fraction part of voltage

//char buf = getCharSerial4();
   //Clear Screen
LCD_sendbyte(0b00000001, 0); 
while (1)
{
    x = ADC_getval();
    //ADC2String(LDR_arr, x);
    
    
    /* max voltage = 3.3V, max LDR value = 255
     * 255/3.3 = 77.3 so use 77 for division
     * int_part = LDR value/77
     * frac_part = (LDRvalue * 100)/77 - int_part*100, giving first 2 DP as integer
     */
    int_part = x/77;
    frac_part = (x*100)/77 - int_part * 100;

    // and format as a string using sprintf (see GitHub readme)
    // %02d ensures that 2 numbers are always displayed frac_part
    // e.g. frac_part = 5, get 0.05 after decimal instead of 0.5 
    // which would get if used %01d or 0.005 if used %03d
    sprintf(LDR_arr,"%d.%02dV",int_part,frac_part);

    sendStringSerial4(LDR_arr); // send voltage to RealTerm
    
    __delay_ms(1000);
    LCD_sendbyte(0b00000001, 0); //clear screen
    __delay_ms(1.53);
    
  
    
    }
}
    

void sendCharSerial4(char charToSend) {
    while (!PIR4bits.TX4IF); // wait for flag to be set
    TX4REG = charToSend; //transfer char to transmitter


void sendStringSerial4(char *string){
    while(*string!=0){
        sendCharSerial4(*string++);
    }
```

}

Edit if I do

```
sprintf(LDR_arr,"%d.%02dV \n",int_part,frac_part);
```

or

```
sprintf(LDR_arr,"%d.%02dV '\n'",int_part,frac_part);
```

I end up with what the voltages going along a diagonal
[RealTerm with '\n' inside](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fbT6H.png)

Comment: Add `'\n'` to your `sprintf`... Maybe you will also need an explicit `'\r'` depending on your terminal.

Comment: You want to do `sprintf(LDR_arr,"%d.%02dV\r\n",int_part,frac_part);` or configure your teraterm to properly display newlines with NL not with CRNL

Comment: Thank you @Eugene, the  ` '\r' ` got it to work, what exactly do  ` '\n' ` and  ` '\r' ` do though? I've never had to use them before. I though that ` '\n' ` would just create a new line but it didn't seem to work like that and I hadn't heard of ` '\r' ` before.

Comment: New line is usually comprised of a "LineFeed" character(LF) - the one which will move the "caret" to the next line, and the "CarriageReturn" (CR) - the one which will move the caret to the start of the line. `\n` might be interpreted like both or just like LF only. `\r` is CR.

Comment: Thanks so much for explaining [@Eugene], I'm pretty new to c programming and this is my first attempt at serial communication so I really appreciate the help

Comment: I read "I'm learning embedded c for microcontrollers using a PICKIT." and thought it was "...  using a [Pickett.](https://www.sliderulemuseum.com/Pickett.htm)" 

Comment: Aside: 255 more likely matches 255/256*3.3V. than 3.3V. There are 2 roundings/truncations occuring (Voltage to A2D value and integer division). A more precise calculation could be x/256.0*3.3 * 100 or with integer math rounding to nearest: `centiVolts = (x*330  + 256/2)/256`.  or to remain within 16-bit math `(x*165  + 128/2)/128`

Answer (score 0):

You need to do one of perhaps three things:

1. Configure your *terminal* for "LF-only" line ends, so it implicitly inserted a CR before each LF - all terminal emulation software supports such a configuration,
2. explicitly output CR+LF line end: `"\r\n"` in your `sprintf()` calls.
3. Modify your low level serial I/O layer to insert a `\r` before every `\n` ("text mode").

Of those I'd recommend the first one, since for either of the other two you'd still have to configure the terminal software for CR+LF in any case.  It is a coin toss what any particular terminal might be configured for by default - though largely determined by whether it was originally developed for Windows or POSIX perhaps.

In TeraTerm for example:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you look at your ascii table 0x0D is a carriage return CR, 0x0A is a newline. The unix world where C came from or where they developed together tends to be limited to just the new line, before during and after serial terminals default to the separate characters of carriage return (start on a new column) and new line (move down to a new line) the combination is the preferred way to move down and left. \r is carriage return 0x0D and \n is newline 0x0A.

While you can change some dumb terminals to turn a newline into both it is more useful and portable to just do it right in the program.  So as pointed out in a comment add \r\n to the end of the string to be printed (or the beginning, your choice).